# Showing that a graph which is a subspace of $\bigoplus \mathcal{H}_i \oplus \bigoplus \mathcal{H}_i $ is closed.

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis, operator-theory, unbounded-operators

Let $\mathcal{H}_i$ be a collection of Hilbert spaces, and $T_i \in \mathbf{B}(\mathcal{H}_i)$. Assume that $\sup ||T_i|| = \infty$. Consider $\bigoplus \mathcal{H}_i$(the completetion). Given an operator $T$ defined on a subspace $D(T)$ into $\bigoplus \mathcal{H}_i$ where $D(T) := \{f \in \bigoplus \mathcal{H}_i: \sum ||T_i(f(i))||^2 < \infty \}$. Essentially this is the definition of an unbounded operator. Where $T := \bigoplus T_i$ i.e. $T(f)(i) := (T_i(f(i))$. I want to show that the graph of $T$ is closed i.e. $G(T) = \{(f, Tf): f \in D(T)\}$ is closed in $\bigoplus \mathcal{H}_i \oplus \bigoplus \mathcal{H}_i$. Given a limit point in this graph $(f, g)$, there is a sequence $(f_n, Tf_n)$ that converges to $(f, g)$. I have shown that $\lim f_n(i) = f(i)$. Since $T_i$ is bounded, then $\lim T(f_n(i)) = T(f(i))$. I am having trouble showing that $\sum ||T_i(f(i))||^2 < \infty$.

Also assume each $T_i$ is self adjoint(I don't know if that will help)

Comment: Hint: $\lim T(f_n(i)) = T(f(i))$ is related to weak convergence of $Tf_n\to g$ and $Tf_n\to g$ converges strongly by assumption.

Comment: @dsh $T$ is not necessarily a bounded operator. I am a bit confused since I thought strong convergence is related to my bounded operators.

Comment: $Tf_n\to g$ converges strongly and (thus) weakly. From $\lim T(f_n(i)) = T(f(i))$ for all $i$ it follows (using weak convergence in $\mathcal{H}_i$ and comparing with weak convergence in $\mathcal{H}$) that $g = Tf.$  As $g$ has finite norm, it follows that $Tf$ has finite norm. Maybe be I missed something.

Comment: oh, wait, I see what you mean about strong and weak convergence. The reason why I was confused since I had only seen the definitions of strong and weak convergence for the strong and weak topology of bounded operators. I didn't realize we can generalize. Thanks for help even though this question was straightfordward looking back at it. @dsh